# Bootstrap 3 - What does initial-scale=1.0 do?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I often see the following on a web page using Bootstrap 3:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

What does inital-scale=1.0 do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the viewport meta tag, the `initial-scale` determines the zoom level when the page is first loaded. (So `initial-scale = 1.0` would reset the zoom back to 100%).

Taken from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: Hmm... I guess this begs the question, "What does it mean to zoom a page"?

Comment: Like, ah...when you press Ctrl + scroll? And everything gets scaled up/down by a factor.